# Python count() type error when passing char casted number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to count the characters in a string this way:

```
randomString = 'a-sasdqwe3123d234wdd213dsad12da-sd-sa'
for number in range(256):
    print(randomString.encode('utf-8').count(chr(number)))
```

From what I understand, `char(55)` for example should give a `7` and `char(85)` a letter `U`, both valid inputs for `count()` function.

The above code snippet returns

`TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'`

Any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: Remove the `.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An encoded string is a bytes-like object, which means it can only count integers, not strings. Get rid of the chr().

```py
randomString = 'a-sasdqwe3123d234wdd213dsad12da-sd-sa'
for number in range(256):
    print(randomString.encode('utf-8').count(number))
```

Alternatively, don't encode it:

```py
randomString = 'a-sasdqwe3123d234wdd213dsad12da-sd-sa'
for number in range(256):
    print(randomString.count(chr(number)))
```